# Can't retrieve entity config

Tags: magento, config

I am creating a module (my first one, without tutorials) and have received the error

'Can't retrieve entity config'

after looking around various sites and trying different options, i've come to a stop. I assume from the full message:

```
Error in file: "/Users/myname/Sites/magentotest/app/code/local/Ps/Pref/sql/pref_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php" - Can't retrieve entity config: pref/prefNewsSignUp
```

That the problem is with my config.xml and that I need to add an entity node somewhere containing something to do with mysql4.....but where I need to add that and what I need to put in that node remains a mystery to me at the moment. My config file is

```
<global>
    <model>
        <pref>
            <class>Ps_Pref_Models</class>
        </pref>
    </model>

    <resources>
        <pref_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Ps_Pref</module>
                <class>Ps_Pref_Models_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </pref_setup>
    </resources>
</global>
```

==============================**EDIT**================================

I have now gone back to the tutorial stage to try and understand where I am going wrong. [this Alan Storm tutorial](http://alanstorm.com/magento_models_orm)  seems very similar to what i'm aiming for, but I still come across the same problem of  "Can't retrieve entity config" (I have gone through all my config and var_dumped various options in IndexController, but cant get passed the problem, and this is not making any sense to me) I have left a couple of the var_dumps that I think will be useful and what they have returned (I hope this edit isn't too confusing)

FOLDER STRUCTURE

+Ps

-+Prefcentre

--+Model

---+Mysql4

----Preferences.php

---Preferences.php

--+controllers

---IndexController.php

--+etc

---config.xml

Ps/Prefcentre/Model/Mysql4/Preferences

```
class Ps_Prefcentre_Model_Mysql4_Preferences
extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('prefcentre/preferences', 'prefcentre_id');
}
}
```

Ps/Prefcentre/Model/Preferences

```
class Ps_Prefcentre_Model_Preferences
extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('prefcentre/preferences');
}
}
```

Ps/Prefcentre/IndexController

```
class Ps_Prefcentre_IndexController
extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
public function indexAction()
{
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $prefs = Mage::getModel('prefcentre/preferences');
    echo ("Loading the blogpost with an Id of " . $params['id']);
    $prefs->load($params['id']);//returns "Can't retrieve entity config"
//        $prefs->getData('title');//returns array(0)
    $data = $prefs->getData();
    var_dump($data);

//        $pref = Mage::getModel('prefcentre/preferences');
//        echo get_class($pref);//returns Ps_Prefcentre_Model_Preferences
}
}
```

Ps/Prefcentre/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
<global>
<!--....-->
    <models>
        <prefcentre>
            <class>Ps_Prefcentre_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>prefcentre_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </prefcentre>

        <prefcentre_mysql4>
            <class>Ps_Prefcentre_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <prefcentre>
                    <table>prefcentre</table>
                </prefcentre>
            </entities>
        </prefcentre_mysql4>  
    </models>
    <resources>
        <prefcentre_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </prefcentre_write>
        <prefcentre_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </prefcentre_read>
    </resources>
<!--....-->
</global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar issue, and my solution was to replace the code below:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $prefs = Mage::getModel('prefcentre/preferences');
    ....
```

for

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $prefs = Mage::getModel('ps_prefcentre/preferences');
    ....
```

That is it, by adding the model prefix I got it sorted.

Answer (score 8):

You are missing a table name reference. Somewhere you are specified a tablename using the handle `pref/prefNewsSignUp` and you have not provided the necessary xpath. Do you have a resource model node? Do you have the appropriate xpath and text under it?

```
<global>
    <model>
        <pref>
            <class>Ps_Pref_Models</class>
            <resourceModel>pref_resource</resourceModel>
        </pref>
        <pref_resource>
            <class>Ps_Pref_Models_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <prefNewsSignUp><table>table_name</table></prefNewsSignUp>
            </entities>
        </pref_resource>
    </model>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did specify a table in sql/prefcentre_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php (is xpath the xml nodes?). I have done what your reply suggests but without success. My script does not run now, I have checked the db and there is no table in pref table in there, so it has not yet run. Guess I need to re-read  http://alanstorm.com/magento_models_orm

Comment: You will also need to make sure that the `_init` call in your resource model contains a handle which maps to the configuration, i.e. `$this->_init('pref/prefNewsSignUp','pk_id');`

Comment: thanks for your help, ive added my code from the tutorial to this thread as I cant seem to get that going either. Could you please advise...I think working this out will answer my question for my first post

Answer (score 1):

```
<model>
    <pref>
        <class>Ps_Pref_Models</class>
    </pref>
</model>
```

Shouldn' t it be :

```
<models>
    <pref>
        <class>Ps_Pref_Model</class>
    </pref>
</models>
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion without success. model or models? i thought they were just dependant on what you named the folders, althought I have just noticed I havnt added my folder structure and that it would be a good idea to add plurals as its probable that many models will go into the fodler

Comment: They are dependent on folder structure, though by convention models belong under a folder named *`Model`*.

Comment: the node should be "models" because it define the models directory. The name should be according to your folder structure, but most common case is Model.